# maximum lifetime of the cookie policy message?

Tags: cookies

When you access to a website with cookie policy message and you accept it, this web sets a cookie in your browser. But anyone know how much time is the maximum lifetime of this cookie?

I'm setting up this cookie message in my website and I want to know how much time can set this cookie.

Thank you

Comment: I want to know if I can set the cookie lifetime for 1 year when the user accept the policy.

Comment: It is technically possible if that's what you're asking.

Comment: I mean, if I can Legally do it.

Comment: Sorry, we are not lawyers here at SO - you might have to post this in some other forum.